# How to filter group's max and min rows using `transform`

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on a task wherein, I need to **filter in** rows that contain the group's max and min values and filter out other rows. This is to understand how the values change at each decile.

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,31),
                  'score' : np.random.uniform(size = 30)})
df    

    id  score
0   1   0.548814
1   2   0.715189
2   3   0.602763
3   4   0.544883
4   5   0.423655
5   6   0.645894
6   7   0.437587
7   8   0.891773
8   9   0.963663
9   10  0.383442
10  11  0.791725
11  12  0.528895
12  13  0.568045
13  14  0.925597
14  15  0.071036
15  16  0.087129
16  17  0.020218
17  18  0.832620
18  19  0.778157
19  20  0.870012
20  21  0.978618
21  22  0.799159
22  23  0.461479
23  24  0.780529
24  25  0.118274
25  26  0.639921
26  27  0.143353
27  28  0.944669
28  29  0.521848
29  30  0.414662
```

I then add the decile column using:

```
df['decile'] = pd.qcut(df['score'], 10, labels=False)
```

Now I tried both:

```
df.transform((df['score'] == df.groupby('decile')['score'].min()) or (df['score'] == df.groupby('decile')['score'].max()))
```

and

```
df.transform(df['score'].eq(df.groupby('decile')['score'].min().values).any() or df['score'].eq(df.groupby('decile')['score'].max().values).any())
```

But both are not working, can someone please help with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) with 2 masks by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) chained by bitwise `OR` - `|`:

```
g = df.groupby('decile')['score']
out = df[df['score'].eq(g.transform('min')) | df['score'].eq(g.transform('max'))]
print (out)
    id     score  decile
1    2  0.715189       6
2    3  0.602763       5
3    4  0.544883       4
5    6  0.645894       5
6    7  0.437587       2
9   10  0.383442       1
10  11  0.791725       7
11  12  0.528895       3
12  13  0.568045       4
13  14  0.925597       8
15  16  0.087129       0
16  17  0.020218       0
17  18  0.832620       7
19  20  0.870012       8
20  21  0.978618       9
22  23  0.461479       3
23  24  0.780529       6
24  25  0.118274       1
27  28  0.944669       9
29  30  0.414662       2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.assign(min=df['score'].eq(g.transform('min')),
                 max=df['score'].eq(g.transform('max')),
                 both = lambda x: x['min'] | x['max']))
```

---

```
    id     score  decile    min    max   both
0    1  0.548814       4  False  False  False
1    2  0.715189       6   True  False   True
2    3  0.602763       5   True  False   True
3    4  0.544883       4   True  False   True
4    5  0.423655       2  False  False  False
5    6  0.645894       5  False   True   True
6    7  0.437587       2  False   True   True
7    8  0.891773       8  False  False  False
8    9  0.963663       9  False  False  False
9   10  0.383442       1  False   True   True
10  11  0.791725       7   True  False   True
11  12  0.528895       3  False   True   True
12  13  0.568045       4  False   True   True
13  14  0.925597       8  False   True   True
14  15  0.071036       0  False  False  False
15  16  0.087129       0  False   True   True
16  17  0.020218       0   True  False   True
17  18  0.832620       7  False   True   True
18  19  0.778157       6  False  False  False
19  20  0.870012       8   True  False   True
20  21  0.978618       9  False   True   True
21  22  0.799159       7  False  False  False
22  23  0.461479       3   True  False   True
23  24  0.780529       6  False   True   True
24  25  0.118274       1   True  False   True
25  26  0.639921       5  False  False  False
26  27  0.143353       1  False  False  False
27  28  0.944669       9   True  False   True
28  29  0.521848       3  False  False  False
29  30  0.414662       2   True  False   True
```

Another idea with lambda function, but solution is slow:

```
out = df[df.groupby('decile')['score'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(x.min()) | x.eq(x.max()))]
```

---

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : range(1,30001),
                  'score' : np.random.uniform(size = 30000)})

df['decile'] = pd.qcut(df['score'], 5000, labels=False)


In [44]: %%timeit
    ...: g = df.groupby('decile')['score']
    ...: out = df[df['score'].eq(g.transform('min')) | df['score'].eq(g.transform('max'))]
    ...: 
3.27 ms ± 239 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: df[df.groupby('decile')['score'].transform(lambda x: x.eq(x.min()) | x.eq(x.max()))]
    ...: 
1.45 s ± 12.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Sorry may be I was not clear, I need rows where the `score` values are equal to group's min and max values, NOT the between values